# Embedded Kafka migration State Store between two instances with different @StreamListener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, embedded-kafka

I have a SpringBoot application with two stream processors mapped via Spring Cloud. Each processor has own @StreamListener for different topics. One processor writes aggregated data to the quarable state store.  I facing the problem in my Unit test when fetching data through my @Service (Service get aggregated data from state store). For some reason from time to time catch exception:

`org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: the state store, recently-played-store, may have migrated to another instance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.QueryableStoreProvider.getStore(QueryableStoreProvider.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.QueryableStoreRegistry.getQueryableStoreType(QueryableStoreRegistry.java:47)`

When I remove StreamListener from another processor all works fine and stable.

How to bind state store for exact instance with proper Processor?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem, maybe it will helps someone else. 
I used not the latest version of spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams. My version was 2.0.0 and it has a bug https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/366 . It was fixed only in the version 2.0.1